# Perform setState after audio is played completely

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Basically I have a recorded audio in the UI which has a play/pause button. there is a `state` property `playing` which decides what icon should be rendered in that button depending on whether `this.state.playing` is `true` or `false`. Now the problem is after the audio is played completely, the pause icon does not get changed to play icon automatically, reason being `this.state.playing` still remains `true`. I understand that I need to perform a `setState` and change `playing` to `false` after the audio play is completed. My question is where should I need to perform the `setState` to ensure it gets executed only after the audio is played completely?

```
state = {
        playing: false
    }

onPlayPause = () => {
        let { playing } = this.state 
        if(playing) {
            this.setState({ playing: false })
            this.audio_el.current.pause()
        } else {
            this.setState({ playing: true })
            this.audio_el.current.play()
            // Need to make {playing: false} only after play() is completed
        }
    }
```

Inside `render()` method:

```
<Button onClick={ this.onPlayPause } icon={ playing ? "pause" : "play" }/>
```

I tried performing `setState` inside `componentDidMount()` but no luck :(

Comment: If you can get the current state of elapsed time and compare that to Total time. then you could possibly set the state if the two times match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bind new method with setState only via media event (more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#media-events) called onEnded on audio element. That should do the work.

You have something like this in render():

```
<audio src="..." onEnded={this.setFinished}>
```

And then add this method:

```
setFinished = () => {
    this.setState({
        playing: false
    })
}
```